# How to disable auto hint popup for a field in Compact Framework?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, mobile

[http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/6879/bb3u.jpg http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/6879/bb3u.jpg](http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/6879/bb3u.jpg)

I have a mobile application written in C# for Windows Mobile 5.

How can disable the auto hint popup for a certain field?

Comment: I have never heard of these hint popups. Can you give some more information on where, when and how they appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SHSetInputContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa932457.aspx) is the api that lets you control the autocomplete for a control.

Alex Feinman has a sample app that shows how to use it linked [here](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.compactframework/browse_thread/thread/96908c7c4cb44a4c/16c75148c52bab3b?lnk=gst&q=Auto+complete&rnum=2&pli=1)

Comment: Do you happen to know if possible to setup the autopopup with my custom content?